# How to extract rows of a dataframe where it has values for more than few columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe,

```
DF = col1    col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7
      A       B       V       0      0       0       0
      G       0       0       0      0       0       0
      D       A       U       N      K       0       0
      E       T       V       A      0       0       0
```

I want to have rows that has values for more than 4 columns,

```
Expected output:
      col1    col2    col3    col4   col5    col6   col7
       D       A       U       N      K       0       0
       E       T       V       A      0       0       0
```

Comment: does my solution solves your problem? If so, could you accept the answer? If not, could you explain why so that I can help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "col1": {0: "A", 1: "G", 2: "D", 3: "E"},
    "col2": {0: "B", 1: "0", 2: "A", 3: "T"},
    "col3": {0: "V", 1: "0", 2: "U", 3: "V"},
    "col4": {0: "0", 1: "0", 2: "N", 3: "A"},
    "col5": {0: "0", 1: "0", 2: "K", 3: "0"},
    "col6": {0: "0", 1: "0", 2: "0", 3: "0"},
    "col7": {0: "0", 1: "0", 2: "0", 3: "0"}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can do it with:

```py
df[(df != "0").sum(axis=1) >= 4]
```

The idea is to count (row wise) the number of elements different from `0` and get only the rows that have at least 4.

Answer (score 0):

inefficiecnt, but if your dataframe is small :

```
df[df.astype(str).replace('0',np.nan).isnull().sum(axis=1) < 4]
```

if your df is big

```
df = df.replace('0', np.nan)
df = df.replace(0,np.nan)

df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < 4]

out:

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5  col6  col7
2    D    A    U    N    K     0     0
3    E    T    V    A    0     0     0
```